# Hide if box is not checked, show if box is checked and dropdown value equals "Other"

Tags: javascript

So selecting Other from the dropdown menu gives you a textbox. And unchecking the box will hide the the textbox and the dropdown menu.

I am unable to directly edit the html to add a div to wrap both the dropdown menu and the textbox together.

The problem I am having is even if Other is not selected, if you uncheck the box, then check it back the Other textbox will display.  I only want the Other textbox to display if the Other dropdown item is selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
// hide otherBox
$('#otherBox').hide();

// show OtherBox if other selected
$('#location_dropdown').change(function() {
    $('#otherBox').toggle(this.value == 'Other');
  });
  
   $('#honor').change(function () {

   
        if (!this.checked) {
           $('#location_dropdown').hide();
           $('.form label').hide();
             } else {
            $('#location_dropdown').show();
            $('.form label').show();
            $('#otherBox').show();
}
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="honor" id="honor" checked="checked" type="checkbox"><label for="tribute_show_honor_fieldsname">Check for yes</label>

<div class="form">


  <label for="location_dropdown"> Location: </label>


</div>

<select name="location_dropdown" selected="selected" id="location_dropdown" size="1">
  <option value="Chicago Center">Chicago Center</option>
  <option value="Columbia">Columbia</option>
  <option value="Lower Manhattan">Lower Manhattan Hospital</option>
  <option  value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<br />
<input name="otherBox" id="otherBox" value="" maxlength="255" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$('#otherBox').show();`, and add the two lines of code commented below:

```
$('#honor').change(function() {
  if (!this.checked) {
    $('#location_dropdown').hide();
    $('.form label').hide();
    $('#otherBox').hide(); //ADD THIS
  } else {
    $('#location_dropdown').show();
    $('.form label').show();
    $('#otherBox').toggle($('#location_dropdown').val() === 'Other');  //ADD THIS
  }
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
// hide otherBox
$('#otherBox').hide();

// show OtherBox if other selected
$('#location_dropdown').change(function() {
  $('#otherBox').toggle(this.value == 'Other');
});

$('#honor').change(function() {
  if (!this.checked) {
    $('#location_dropdown').hide();
    $('.form label').hide();
    $('#otherBox').hide();
  } else {
    $('#location_dropdown').show();
    $('.form label').show();
    $('#otherBox').toggle($('#location_dropdown').val() === 'Other');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="honor" id="honor" checked="checked" type="checkbox"><label for="tribute_show_honor_fieldsname">Check for yes</label>

<div class="form">


  <label for="location_dropdown"> Location: </label>


</div>

<select name="location_dropdown" selected="selected" id="location_dropdown" size="1">
  <option value="Chicago Center">Chicago Center</option>
  <option value="Columbia">Columbia</option>
  <option value="Lower Manhattan">Lower Manhattan Hospital</option>
  <option  value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<br />
<input name="otherBox" id="otherBox" value="" maxlength="255" type="text">
```